# SSL certificae for a local network website

Tags: ssl

My requirement is that I want to have an local network website behind ssl. I know I can create a self signed certificate but I would then need to install certificate on each client (which can be in hundreds and would not be on a domain). If I buy an ssl certificate. how would it help and what sort of ssl certificate do I need to buy?

This web application communicates with two signalR servers which I also want to be behind ssl. I'll be using self signed certificate for that.

I would greatly appreciate any help.
Thanks.